# Best way to bind tooltip text to content of a control?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So, I'm adding tooltips to a WPF form, and basically the tooltips only need to match the content. However, I have `_` in some controls so that they can be selected with ALT+<key>. I of course do not want the _ to be included in the tooltip text.

Also, I'd prefer not having to write the name of the control out a third time for `ElementName=`. This is what I currently have:

```
<CheckBox x:Uid="chkProcess" Name="chkProcess" ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=chkProcess, Path=Content}">_Process widgets</CheckBox>
```

I also have a second method that works but isn't so pretty. It basically attaches to the TollTipOpening event and dynamically changes the tooltip value to match the content with proper stripping of `_` characters.

Is there a clean way of stripping out the _ with databinding or a better way to do this in general?

Answer (score 2):

You could try this : Use label in tooltip that will not show "_"

```
<CheckBox x:Uid="chkProcess" Name="chkProcess">_Process widgets
    <CheckBox.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}">
            <Label Content="{Binding Content}"/>
        </ToolTip>
    </CheckBox.ToolTip>
</CheckBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `ElementName=chkProcess` with `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}`.  While it's more verbose, it might allow you to remove the `Name` attribute as well.

If you want to strip out the `_` characters, you can create a simple `IValueConverter` to perform that task, and specify the `Converter` on your tool tip `Binding`.  However, having a tool tip that simply regurgitates the label that's already displayed seems pointless at best, and annoying at worst.

Comment: For reference, the tooltip is there for if the text scrolls off screen, where a scrollbar would be very ugly to use

Comment: Ah, fair enough.  It would be nice `TextBlock` had a read-only property indicating whether the display text had been trimmed, in which case you could enable text trimming and conditionally enable the tool tip for those cases only.